# Try-catch flow to handle two failing services

Tags: c#

We need to create a car with apiCar and log in two places CosmosDB and the logger, whether there is an error or not. Except if the error happens in Cosmos, in that case we only log in the logger. Finally, if there is an exception, any exception, we need rethrow it so the "MyFunction" caller can handle it.
This is my best shot that works but I don't like it. Is there any way to improve it?

```
public async Task MyFunction(Car car)
{
    try
    {
        var apiCar = await _APIService.CreateAsync(car);
        car.Status = CarStatus.Created;

        _logger.LogInformation("Created apiCar for car: {carId}", car.Id);
    }
    catch (ApiErrorException exception)
    {
        _logger.LogError(exception, "API exception for car: {carId}", car.Id);
        car.Status = CarStatus.Error;
        car.ErrorMessage = exception.Body.Error.Message;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        _logger.LogError(exception, "Exception for car: {carId}", car.Id);
        car.Status = CarStatus.Error;
        car.ErrorMessage = exception.Message;
    }

    try
    {
        await _cosmosService.UpdateItemAsync(car);
    }
    catch (CosmosException exception)
    {
        _logger.LogError(exception, "Cosmos exception for car: {carId}", car.Id);

        throw;
    }

    if (car.Status == CarStatus.Error)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, any `async` function should end with `Async`, ie `MyFunctionAsync`. You can see examples of this in the other `async` functions you're calling throughout your code.

As to your requirements, the exception you throw at the end is devoid of any useful information. It has no exception origination information (line number etc) and no correct stack trace. Either save the exception you're handling in the top `try` when it happens, or even better rethrow it on the spot.

I very much question your updating the item even though the first part errored out, so rethrowing the first set of exceptions on the spot is what I'd do, but if you want to update it even in an error case, bring the update function with you in the `catch` and then rethrow.

The second part is fine, you're rethrowing as you should.

Comment: MyFunctionAsync indeed. Creating a top reference seems convenient. Regarding the update function, we need to log in two places Cosmos and the logger. If I bring the Cosmos update function to each catch, each catch will need to have an inner try-catch for that Cosmos call, so the logger reports the Cosmos failure.

Comment: That's fine, use a local function that does the equivalent of the 2nd `try`..`catch` and call it in as many places as needed.

Comment: If I call the SaveToCosmosWithTryCatch from the first try, the exception it generates will be catched by the general catch, and as a consequence will call SaveToCosmosWithTryCatch twice.

Comment: If you call it from the first try's catch? That's not how try..catch works, only the try part has its exceptions handled. Any exception triggered in a catch is unhandled.

Comment: We need to save the car to Cosmos if everything goes fine, that is if everything in the first try goes fine. That is why I ended with the code in question that I don't like.

Comment: I understand, and what's the problem?

Comment: I ended up factoring out the Cosmos error logging to a method that is called from ApiErrorException and Exception, adding a catch for Cosmos exceptions and duplicating the Cosmos call in the first try. Thanks for your feedback!